# Ninja batch file as command

Tags: windows, batch-file, ninja

I want to use a batch file as a rule command in [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) like this

```
rule test
  command = some-batch-file
```

but it results in

```
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It works when I prefix the command with `cmd /c`, but then I face the problem of the command-line length cap at 8191 or so characters. I found it hard finding information on *why* this doesn't work. My guess is that windows can really only execute `.exe` files with `CreateProcess()`.

Can I make it work when it is passed directly to `CreateProcess()` or do I *have* to use `cmd /c`?

Comment: A batch file is not an executable image. `CreateProcess` can only be used with executable images. The batch file requires the command line interpreter.

Comment: There is no getting around the 8191 byte command line limit for CMD, and a Windows batch file requires CMD.EXE.